# Evitar que se repita un objeto al dar click en un botón

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python y tengo este código de ejemplo para expresar mis dudas.

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
root.config(bg="grey50" )

frame1 = Frame(root,bg= "white")
frame1.place(x=20, y=10, height=100, width=260)



def opcion_uno():

    caja= Entry(frame1, bg= "grey40")
    caja.pack()


def opcion_dos():
    caja2= Entry(frame1, bg= "red")
    caja2.pack()
  



boton1 = Button(root, bg="green4", fg="white", text="Opcion 1", command=opcion_uno)
boton1.place(x=20, y =140)

boton2 = Button(root, bg="green4", fg="white", text="Opcion 2", command=opcion_dos)
boton2.place(x=80, y =140)


root.mainloop()
```

Como pueden ver al dar click en un botón se llama una de las dos funciones en las cuales se crea una caja de texto, lo que quiero saber es si hay algún método para cuando se haya presionado el **botón 2**    y se cree la caja de texto, al dar click en el **boton 1** se elimine la caja de texto que se creo con el **boton 2** y aparesca la caja de texto del **boton 1**, obviamente se puede con **.destroy()** pero luego que le vuelves a dar click al boton donde eliminaste el objeto ya no existe porque se destruyo.

Tambien si hay una opcion de reiniciar o borrar lo que hay dentro de un Frame y luego agregar otros objetos seria mas sencillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para borrar todo lo que hay dentro de un frame puedes utilizar esto

```
def limpiador_de_frames():
    for i in frame.winfo_children():
        i.destroy()
```

winfo.children() lo que hace es buscar todos lo widgets hijos del frame, con el for lo recorres y lo que almecene en i lo destruye.

ahora si quieres ocultar los entrys pack_forget() te puede servir

```
def opcion_uno():
   global caja
   try:
       caja= Entry(frame1, bg= "grey40")
       caja.pack()
       if caja2:
          caja2.pack_forget()
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)

def opcion_dos():
    global caja2
    try:
        caja2= Entry(frame1, bg= "red")
        caja2.pack()
        if caja:
           caja.pack_forget()
    except Exception as e:
          print(e)
```

espero te pueda servir.

Answer (score 0):

Hola muchas gracias al final me las ingenie para que funcionara como quería.

```
from tkinter import *

v = Tk()
v.geometry("240x240+500+200")
v.title("Prueba")


f1= Frame(v, bg="grey15")
f1.place(x=20, y= 10, width=200, height=80)


def limpiador_de_frames():
        for i in f1.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()

def op_1():

    limpiador_de_frames()
    c2 = Entry(f1, bg="blue")
    c2.place(x=20, y= 10)


def op_2():

    limpiador_de_frames()
    c1 = Entry(f1, bg="red")
    c1.place(x=20, y= 30)



    
bt1 = Button(v, text="1", command=op_1)
bt1.place(x=20, y= 195)

bt2 = Button(v, text="2", command=op_2)
bt2.place(x=40, y= 195)

v.mainloop()
```